# Making test cases maintainable

Tags: testing, agile

How to make the test cases maintainable or generic in an agile environment , where there is frequent changes in the requirements.

This is a question that was asked to my friend in an interview.

Comment: Have good design based on those frequenct changes.  One point about test cases is to be testing the important functionality so that future changes can confirm they did not break previously added features.  So it depends what you mean by frequenct changes, like rip out features recently added and replacing; or add new features on top of existing.

Comment: What did your friend answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Write tests at higher level of abstraction

  - Write intent revealing tests rather than tests that mimic the user clicks on UI
  - Use BDD frameworks like Spock, Cucumber etc.
- Re-use: Identify the reusable features and re-use them. For e.g. Login feature steps can be written once and re-used across other features

  - Write more tests at service level than from the end-to-end
- Use formal techniques to reduce the number of regression tests

  - Equivalence Class Partitioning
  - Combinatorial Testing
  - Boundary Values
- Create a test strategy for the entire team

  - Move white-box testing to unit and integration tests
  - Clearly identify what will be automated by testers and what should be automated by developers. For e.g. most of the white box tests can be realized using unit tests. [Testing Quadrants](http://lisacrispin.com/wordpress/category/agile-testing-quadrants/) is what I use heavily.
- And most importantly ditch tools from vendors like mercury and IBM.

Comment: OH why can't I favorite an answer D= ... +1 I found this very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

My short answer to this is treat your test suite with the same respect you treat the rest of your code base.

Automated test are code - important code. Pay as much attention to keeping them well factored and clean as you do everything else and you can't go far wrong.